# Ajax file upload: what happens by default in form.onsubmit()?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a Java servlet that receives a file, processes it and then writes the resulting file back through HttpServletResponse's OutputStream.

For upload, I use a simple form:

```
<form id="upload-form" action="MyServlet" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to convert: 
    <input type="file" id="file-select" name="myfile" />
    <button type="submit" id="upload-button">Upload</button>
</form>
```

After the file has been processed, a download dialog opens automatically.

Since processing may take a while (something like 30 seconds plus upload time), I wanted to provide some progress information through a websocket on the same page. This works if I do this:

```
var uploadForm = document.getElementById("upload-form");
var fileSelect = document.getElementById("file-select");
var uploadButton = document.getElementById("upload-button");
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

uploadForm.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var file = fileSelect.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("myfile", file, file.name);

    httpRequest.open("POST", "MyServlet", true);
    httpRequest.send(formData);
};
```

The essential commands here seem to be event.preventDefault and event.stopPropagation.

The thing is: with this code, I get my progress info - but my download window never appears. If I comment out the two commands, it's the other way around. What happens by default when submitting a form, and (how) can I trigger that manually, so that I get both progress info AND the resulting file?

Note: I'm not using jQuery so far.

Comment: I think you should add in `httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { ... }` and `httpRequest.onerror = function() { ... }` to see if your JS is actually sending the request, and if you get anything back from server.

Comment: Hmm. `onreadystatechange` is called several times, finally `onload` is called, so I suppose that's the way to go. But what do I need to call there in order to get the download window?